# React native index.js and import react

Tags: react-native

I am learning react native. My index.js file is like below :

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

const RNRedux = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('redux1', () => RNRedux);
```

Now, my question is :
"React" is not used anywhere. So, why am I importing it here ? If I comment it out then I am getting an error "Cant find variable: React". 
Does react native need it ? If so, then why react native haven't imported it ? Is there any reason behind it ?

I understand that I am importing "react" in my App.js file as I am using Component.

Thank you.

** I have found my answer. I have forgot that I have used JSX in the index.js file and for that I need to import react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React includes what’s necessary for the JSX syntax. If you don’t import React, you can’t use JSX.